# Can someone explain the arguments to write function used for the curl option CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION

Tags: curl

From http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html:

> So, you write your own function that matches this prototype:
>
> ```
>  size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
> ```
>
> You tell libcurl to pass all data to this function by issuing a
>   function similar to this:
>
> ```
>  curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
> ```

Can someone explain what the arguments `size` and `nmemb` stand for? Is `size` the number of characters in the response? Then what is `nmemb`?

Answer (score 9):

Apparently ["**size** is the size of one data item, **nmemb** is the number of data items"](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.curl.library/35520). My guess is that it's some internal implementation detail. The **real data size = size * nmemb**.

The documentation for the callback function:  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html

Example code:
https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/examples/getinmemory.c

Comment: This was really important, something that I have overlooked. You are absolutely correct about  size * nmemb.

Answer (score 5):

This is designed for the function such as: `size_t fwrite(const void* buffer, size_t size, size_t count, FILE* stream);`

```
FILE* out = fopen("out.html", "w");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)out);
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, fwrite);
```

So we need not to add more code for `fwrite` as it is!